# How to convert a predefined function callback into promise

Tags: node.js, async-await, node-modules, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I have code that connects with snowflake to execute a query. I want to extract the data from the complete key which has a callback function implemented. Is there is any way if I can stop the function till it gives the complete information.  Like using await or something

```
var statement = connection.execute({
        sqlText: 'select sysdate() from dual'
        ,complete: function(err, stmt, rows) {
        if (err) {
            context.error('Failed to execute statement due to the following error: ' + err.message);
        } else {
            context.log('Successfully executed statement: ' + stmt.getSqlText());
            }
        }
    });
```

Edit 1:

if I use

```
console.log(statement.getStatus()) //output is  {fetching}
```

But What I need is a complete status.

Comment: what do you want to stop ? the `getSqlText()` ?

Comment: what ever you want to do next or after you function does something put it inside the callback.. it might be difficult to get the point but that is how things are if you function supports promises then great you can use async which will look cleaner https://dev.to/reddyaravind178/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-5gpf

Answer (score 5):

You cannot transform an asynchronous function into a synchronous one. If you want your code to look like a synchronic, then you can use `async/await`. Example of the wrapper function `execAsync`, for using `async/await`:

```js
function execAsync(connection, sqlText) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.execute({
            sqlText: sqlText,
            complete: (err, stmt, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                } 
                return resolve([stmt, rows]);
            }
        });
    });
}

(async () => {
    try {
        const [statement, rows] = await execAsync(connection, 'select sysdate() from dual');
        console.log(statement.getStatus());
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Hi @Rustam, In last block of code can't we use only try catch block. Is it necessary to use (async () => {try-catch-block})();. If not can you explain what this block is doing I am not able to understand.

Comment: `await` can only be used in `async` functions. The code block `(async () => {}) ()` is an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) that wraps our code in the `async` function and allows us to use `await`. And the `try...catch` block allows us to catch an error if it occurs in the `execAsync` function.

Comment: Hi @Rustam, when I used var somevar = (async () => {return something}) () and console.log(somevar).. it gives output Promise { <pending> }. Is there any way I can wait for the output to come.

Comment: You should not use the `(async () => {})()` construct in your code, if you want to return something, then there is a function somewhere in your code, you must declare it as `async` and use in her `await` as I showed in the answer. I do not see your complete code, so I can not help somehow explicitly.

Comment: Hi @RustamD9RS can we do the same for connection.connect({}) too?

Answer (score 0):

The complete callback is invoked when a statement has finished executing and the **result is ready to be consumed**. So it already works as you want. You do not need to wait.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#executing-statements

Comment: I want to wait for the function to get executed